# How to stop Python 'import' from importing the filename as well?

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
  \__ module/
        \__ __init__.py
        \__ stuff.py
```

The `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from . import stuff as othername
```

However, when I open up the python interactive interpreter and import the module, `module`, and call `dir()` on the module, I get the following result:

```
>>> dir(module)
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 ...
 'othername',
 'stuff']
```

As you can see, the name of the file, `stuff` (minus the .py extension), is still present.

Without simply changing the name of `stuff.py` to `othername.py`, how would I import `stuff` as `othername`, without also import `stuff` as `stuff`?

Also, on a sidenote, what's the best way to provide an alias for the same module?

Is this how is supposed to be done...

```
from . import stuff as othername
aliasname = othername
```

...or is there another way that is considered the "correct" way to do it?

### **UPDATE**

I tried setting `__all__` manually within my `__init__.py` file, but the name of the file itself is still being included in the import.

`__init__.py:`

```
from . import stuff as othername
from . import stuff as aliasname

__all__ = [ 'othername', 'aliasname' ]
```

I've managed to get the following to work, but I don't know if it would be considered "good practice" or if it would even provide consistent behavior:

`__init__.py:`

```
from . import stuff as othername
from . import stuff as aliasname

del stuff
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this important? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For your side note: When things work, there's no major difference between `aliasname = othername` vs. `from . import stuff as aliasname` or any other alternative, so it comes down to which is more readable/obvious for your particular use—which really depends on why you're creating an alias in the first place.

Comment: For your main problem: I think the issue is that a package automatically contains any submodules that have been imported. You could hack around that by replacing the package's `__class__` with a subclass of `ModuleType`, or you could build a custom importlib loader for it, or you could change it from a real package to a fake package that aliases (just the names you want from) a secret real package… But an easier solution might be to just use an `__all__` that doesn't include `stuff`, or rename `stuff.py` to `_stuff.py`, and then not worry about it. Or, even easier, do nothing and not worry…

Comment: I'm writing a C lexical analyzer. There are multiple version of C (i.e. c89, c90, c99, c11), but c89 and c90 are basically the same thing. So I want the code for the c89 code to be in a file with a name like `lex_c89.py`, but I want to import it with names `c89` and `c90`. Ultimately, it's not important per say, but it would give the module I am creating a nicer interface/look.

Comment: @abarnert, I just read up on Python's special `__all__` variable (I'm a noob). That is the answer I was looking for. If you feel like posting that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @abarnert, actually setting `__all__` doesn't seem to be working... I'll add an update to my question showing what I am doing.

Comment: Well, the other options are all still on the table… but meanwhile, you still haven't told us why you're doing this, why it matters that `module.stuff` exists, etc.

Comment: @abarnert, I explained in my above comment why I am doing this (the one regarding a C lexical analyzer). Not sure whether or not it's a valid reason, but it makes sense in my head at least haha.

Comment: Look forward to Python 3.7 where you will be able to specify a module `__dir__`.  Details [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/).

Comment: `if stuff: del stuff` checks to see if `stuff` is truthy, not to see if it's defined. It will give a name error if it doesn't exist. To achieve the same thing, you could do `try: del stuff` `except NameError: pass`.

Comment: @wim You can already do that in 3.6 and 2.7 by replacing the package's `__class__` with a subclass of `ModuleType`, as I mentioned above. Ugly, but then `__getattr__` and/or `__dir__` is also ugly, it's just easier to implement.

Comment: @zondo, Thank you, you are right! I just updated what I wrote.

Comment: Anyway, I think the best answer here (if "do nothing and not worry" isn't acceptable, and renaming `stuff.py` to `_stuff.py` isn't possible) is to make this a "hidden" package, and create another simple "public" package that sits in front of it and has nothing but aliases to exactly the things you want to from the public one. It's not beautiful, but it's not hard to write, or to understand.

Comment: Opinions differ, I don't think module `__getattr__` and `__dir__` features are ugly.  I do think patching `__class__` is ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *prevent* the module being assigned under its real name.  After all, the following has to set attributes `foo` *and* `bar` on the package module object:

```
# pkg/__init__.py
from .foo import bar
```

You can of course `del` the name after it's been added (by `import`ing it):

```
# pkg/__init__.py
from . import foo as bar
del foo
```

But watch out: it leads to strange situations like

```
>>> import pkg.foo
>>> from pkg.foo import a
>>> pkg.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pkg' has no attribute 'foo'
>>> import pkg.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pkg.bar'
>>> pkg.bar.a is a
True
>>> from pkg.bar import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pkg.bar'
```

Of course this doesn't matter so much if the *status* of `pkg.bar` as a module is considered an implementation detail, so that no one will be issuing `import`s like these.  It also matters less if you're *adding* an alias without suppressing the true name.   (In your case, why not call `lex_c89.py` just `c89.py`?  The whole package is a lexer anyway…)   Even then, such hiding precludes the performance benefit of importing only the modules that you need, since the user can't indicate what they need.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I didn't know about the potential issues that came with deleting the real name of the module.